# Objectbox flutter apple silicon emulator support

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

Does objectbox flutter support ios emulator on M1 macbooks?

I get this error despite following `Getting started` guide, however it works fine in CI which also runs on M1 chip (but against physical phone engine snapshot, not the emulator)

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ObjectBox":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    ObjectBox (= 1.7.0)

  In Podfile:
    objectbox_flutter_libs (from `.symlinks/plugins/objectbox_flutter_libs/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      ObjectBox (= 1.8.1)

Specs satisfying the `ObjectBox (= 1.7.0), ObjectBox (= 1.8.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

From [what I can see](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-swift#swift-versions), 1.7.2 requires swift 5.7.2 which according to a quick google search should be supported by ios 14

I've tried rolling back to 1.6.2 and changing deployment target up to 14 (from 11) but the error is still there.

How do I fix that?

Comment: I would expect the iOS simulator to use an arm64 target on M1 macs, so why are you trying to use x86_64?

Comment: sorry my bad, it's actually `arm64-apple-ios-simulator`

Answer (score 1):

I deleted `Podfile.lock` and then ran `flutter pub get` followed by `pod install` which seems to have solved the issue